How to code Label segregation after Screening in Pine Script V5?
I am unable to segregate and have two labels, one as Stocks screened for Buy and another for Sell.
I don't know how to create, and I am able to create one, where all come together.
I tried for one label and it is working fine. I need to have two separate labels, one has stocks screened as buy out of 40 and another as sell list. Below is the code.
//@version=5
indicator('Open/OR 5M', shorttitle="OP", overlay=true)

//################################################
//Open Price Line and 5 Min Opening Range

tz_increment = input.int(-4, 'UTC (+/-)', tooltip = 'New York is -4')
use_exchange = input(false, 'Use Exchange Timezone')

OR_sess = input.session('0915-0920', title='Opening Range Session')
OR_t = time(timeframe.period, OR_sess + ':1234567', use_exchange ? syminfo.timezone : 'GMT+0530')

show_mid = input.bool(true,"Show Mid levels")
chg_col = input.bool(true,"Level changes color", tooltip="Lines change color based on whether the      closing price is above or below the line")

var opening = 0.0

opening := OR_t and not(OR_t[1]) ? open : opening[1]

OR_in_session = not na(OR_t)
OR_is_first = OR_in_session and not OR_in_session[1]

OR_h = float(na)
OR_l = float(na)

if OR_is_first
    OR_h := high
    OR_l := low
    OR_l
else
    OR_h := OR_h[1]
    OR_l := OR_l[1]
    OR_l
if high > OR_h and OR_in_session
    OR_h := high
    OR_h
if low < OR_l and OR_in_session
    OR_l := low
    OR_l

OR_mid = (OR_h + OR_l) / 2

OR_line_col(_src)=>
    chg_col and close > _src ? color.new(color.green,40) : chg_col and close < _src ? color.new(color.red,40) : #dfc800b2


plot(timeframe.isintraday ? opening : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= #00000065, title='Opening price', linewidth=3)

plot(timeframe.isintraday ? OR_h : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= OR_in_session[1] or   OR_in_session ? na : OR_line_col(OR_h), title='OR High', linewidth=2)
plot(timeframe.isintraday ? OR_l : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= OR_in_session[1] or OR_in_session ? na : OR_line_col(OR_l), title='OR Low', linewidth=2)
plot(show_mid and timeframe.isintraday ? OR_mid : na, style=plot.style_circles, color= OR_in_session[1] or OR_in_session ? na : OR_line_col(OR_mid), title='OR Mid', linewidth=1)

buy = OR_h == opening
sell = OR_l == opening

//################################
//---------------------------------------------------------------
screen() =>
    buy or sell

//------------------------------------------------------

// Counts
var BarCount = 0 
var ExtVolcount = 0
if close > 0
    BarCount := BarCount + 1

//------------------------------------------------------
tf = input.timeframe("5")

s1 = input.symbol('NSE:NIFTY', 'Symbol 1', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s2 = input.symbol('NSE:NIFTY Bank', 'Symbol 2', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s3 = input.symbol('NSE:Abcapital', 'Symbol 3', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')  
s4 = input.symbol('NSE:Adanient', 'Symbol 4', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')
s5 = input.symbol('NSE:Adaniports', 'Symbol 5', inline='1', group='STOCK LIST')

c1 = request.security(s1, tf, screen())
c2 = request.security(s2, tf, screen())
c3 = request.security(s3, tf, screen())
c4 = request.security(s4, tf, screen())
c5 = request.security(s5, tf, screen())

//------------------------------------------------------------------------

entry_label = '*5MTF OP/OR EQL-1-40*\n'
entry_label := c1 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s1) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c2 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s2) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c3 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s3) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c4 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s4) + '\n' : entry_label
entry_label := c5 ? entry_label + str.tostring(s5) + '\n' : entry_label


lab_entry = label.new(bar_index + 20, close, entry_label, color=#0307ffb2, textcolor=#ffffff, style=label.style_label_up, yloc=yloc.price, textalign=text.align_left)

label.delete(lab_entry[1])

